# First link under header tag is unclickable

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have an issue with a classic ASP VBScript page which is starting to bug me. For the record I am not a web designer and I am working on somebody else code.

I have a strange issue where the first set of links that appear directly under a header cannot be clicked, but any after the first row can. I assume this is some kind of issue with overlapping elements on the page, but alas, the answer eludes me after 2 hours of trying to fix it.

Example below from the loop that creates the headers (the first loop). Any ideas as to why this is happening would be great.

Thanks

[image: Example]

```html
 <div id="folderWrapper" style="width:100%; text-align:left; display:inline; float:left;">
        <!-- Loop through the folders in the  specific directories to find all that start with a "_" (where documents are stored) -->
        <%
        dim fs,fo,x
        set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        set fo=fs.GetFolder(server.MapPath(department))
        for each x in fo.SubFolders
        %>
                <%If Left(x.Name, 1) = "_" Then%>
                <!-- Run the loop against only folders with the appendix of "_" as these are the folders with the files in.-->
                    <div id="folderDiv" style="width:100%; text-align:left; display:inline; float:left; padding-right:10px;">
                    <!-- Create headers for each folder-->
                    <h6><%Response.Write(Right(x.Name,len(x.Name)-1))%></h6>
                        <%
                        ' Loop through files in folder
                        dim fs2,fo2,x2
                        set fs2=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                        set fo2=fs2.GetFolder(x)
                        for each x2 in fo2.files

                        ' Set fileType variable depending upon the left 4 or 5 chars.
                        dim fileType 
                        If (Right(x2.Name,4)=".doc") or (Right(x2.Name,4)=".pdf") Then
                            fileType = Right(x2.Name,4)
                        End If
                        If (Right(x2.Name,5)=".docx") Then 
                            fileType = Right(x2.Name,5)
                        End If
                        %>
                            <!-- DIV to contain the files and display the correct icon for .doc/.docx and .pdf files-->
                            <div id="fileDiv" style="width:450px; float:left; display:inline; margin-left:10px; background-image:url(../images/<%if (right(x2.Name,4) = ".doc") or (right(x2.Name,4) = "docx") then %>Word_Icon.gif <%end if%> <%if(right(x2.Name,4) = ".pdf") then %>PDF_Icon.gif <% end if %> ); background-position:left; background-repeat:no-repeat; padding:10px 10px 10px 25px;" >
                                <%If fileType <> ".db" Then%>
                                    <!-- If to deal with .doc and .pdf files (removes the .doc/.pdf extensions from the name when displayed on the page)-->
                                    <%If (fileType=".doc") or (fileType=".pdf") Then%>
                                        <a href="./<%Response.Write(department) %>/<%=x.Name%>/<%=x2.Name%>" target="Form"><%=left(x2.Name,len(x2.Name)-4)%></a>
                                    <%End If%>
                                    <!-- If to deal with .docx files (removes the .docx extensions from the name when displayed on the page)-->
                                    <%If (fileType=".docx") Then %>
                                        <a href="./<%Response.Write(department)%>/<%=x.Name%>/<%=x2.Name%>" target="Form"><%=left(x2.Name,len(x2.Name)-5)%></a>
                                    <%End If%>
                                <%End If%>
                            </div>
                        <%next
                        set fo=nothing
                        set fs=nothing%>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                            </div>
                <%End If%>

        <%next
        set fo=nothing
        set fs=nothing%>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you right-click on "Forms" and select "Inspect" then show us what the CSS looks like?

Comment: Hi @Scott, this was resolved thankfully. I will update the post.

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused due to a   tag overlapping the first div. This was originally intended to provide a buffer between the div before and this div but a this was removed and padding added instead.